# Why bitwise OR operator is used in flag enum with meaning AND

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

It might be an easy and simple question but I still have a little confusion the reason why bitwise `OR` is decided to use. Assume I have a class `A` with four fields:

```
class A
{
    private int Field1;
    private static int Field2;
    public int Field3;
    public static int Field4;
}
```

And use `Reflection` to get fields:

```
var fields = typeof (A).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

If you are newbie with `Reflection` and don't know the way how to use `BindingFlags`, the initial logic thinking in your head would be:

This line will select all static OR public fields because bitwise OR is used. And the expected result you think:

```
Field2
Field3
Field4
```

But when hitting F5, the result will be totally different, bitwise `OR` works as `AND`:

```
Field4
```

Why not use bitwise AND operator which might follow with the logic thinking. like this:

```
var fields = typeof (A).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public & BindingFlags.Static);
```

I found words in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx):

> the bitwise OR operation used to combine the flags might be considered an advanced concept in some circumstances that should not be required for simple tasks.

Please could anyone explain the *advance concept* in here in simple way for understanding?

Comment: `OR` seems to be the right concept here when you consider the difference between inclusive and exclusive OR. In this case the `OR` is inclusive, the same as saying "pick me up some items from the store that contain eggs or ham". That's different than saying "that contain eggs AND ham".

Comment: in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx) you read : You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance **or** BindingFlags.Static in order to get a return. So may be you can't list instance **and** static at the same time... ??

Comment: @tschmit007: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth:imho, It may explain why GetFields only returns Field4.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See the end for a short summary.

**Long answer:**

Bitwise OR is combining the bits of the enum flags.

Example:

- `BindingFlags.Public` has the value of 16  or 10000 (binary)
- `BindingFlags.Static` has the Value of 8  or  1000 (binary)

bitwise OR combines these like the following:

```
10000
01000
--
11000  --> 24
```

bitwise AND would combine them like this:

```
10000
01000
--
00000   --> 0
```

That's a very basic concept of Flags:
Each value is a power of two, e.g.:

- 1 = `2^0`
- 2 = `2^1`
- 4 = `2^2`
- 8 = `2^3`
- etc.

Their bit representation is always a `1` and the rest zeros:

```
decimal | binary
1       | 0001
2       | 0010
4       | 0100
8       | 1000
```

Combining any of them using bitwise AND would always lead to 0 as there are no `1` at the same position. Bitwise AND would lead to a complete information loss.

Bitwise OR on the other hand will always result in an unambiguous result. For example, when you have (binary) 1010 (decimal 10) you know it originally has been 8 and 2. There is no other possibility 10 could have been created.
As Default said, the method you called can later extract this information using the bitwise AND operator:

```
if(10 & 8 == 8) // value 8 was set
```

**The bitwise OR in this case is basically a vehicle to transport the values to the method you are calling.**
What this method does with these values has nothing to do with the usage of bitwise OR.
It can internaly require ALL passed flags to match as is the case for `GetFields`. But it also could require only one of the passed flags to match.

For you as a caller, the following would be equivalent:

```
var requiredFlags = new List<BindingFlags>();
requiredFlags.Add(BindingFlags.Public);
requiredFlags.Add(BindingFlags.Static);
typeof (A).GetFields(requiredFlags);
```

Now that doesn't compile as `GetFields` doesn't provide such an overload, but the meaning would be the same as that of your code.

**To sum things up (TL;DR):**

Bitwise AND has nothing to do with Boolean AND
Bitwise OR has nothing to do with Boolean OR

Comment: which **later** will be used with the `&` operator as `if (userArgument & BindingFlags.Public){ /* add to return value */ }`

Answer (score 2):

The flag enum is being used to represent a set of boolean conditions.

In your example, each boolean condition must be fulfilled for the corresponding field to be returned.

Flag enums are simply integral values that obey the usual binary rules for anding and oring, so to set several bits you must OR together the values representing those bits.

Once you have done so, you have a flag enum with the appropriate bits set.

The problem you are having is because you are conflating two different concepts: The way that you construct the set of boolean conditions for a flag enum is one concept. The way that the flag enum is used (or what it represents) is a different concept.

The former uses OR to construct the set of boolean conditions. The latter says that each bit represents a boolean condition that must be fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

The implementers of GetFields() chose to *interpret* the combination of various ORed flags as meaning an AND combination of the selected criteria.

Which makes sense as you can always drop a criterion if you don't want the additional filter.